# C programming — binary search

Tags: c, search, binary

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

 int array[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
 int size = 10;
 int number = 3;
 int min = 0;
 int max = size -1;


 int g = (min + max) / 2;
 while(g > 0)
 {
   if(array[g] == number)
   {
   printf("found number: %i\n", array[g]);
   return true;
   }
   else if(array[g] < number)
   {
   printf("middle point %i is lower than number %i\n", array[g], number);
   min = g/2 + 1;
   return min;
   }
   else if (array[g] > number)
   {
   printf("middle point %i is higher than number\n", array[g]);
   max = g/2 - 1;
   return max;
   }
 }
}
```

Is it possible to change the int value even if it is out of scope? Or do I have to take completely different approach for this?

Comment: I mean it just gets stuck printf("middle point %i is lower than number %i\n", array[g],     number) And keeps printing - middle point 5i is lower than number 3.

Comment: Part of the problem is that `return` from a `main()` exits the program.  Even if you were in a `binary_search()` function, it isn't clear that you'd necessarily want to return the values as shown.  You seem to do one iteration of the loop, returning in every case (when the number is equal to, less than, or greater than the tested array element).  You need to rethink the algorithm (or, you would if you hadn't solved it a year ago).